# Reordering Tables in ArcMap Layer List?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, oracle-dbms, table

I'm trying to reorder the TABLES in my ArcMap layer list. I can't find a way to do it. I can reorder normal layers since they appear in the "List by Drawing Order" tab of the "Table of Contents".

The reason why the order is important for the tables is that when I publish this to an ArcGIS Server as a map service the tables get an ID based on their order. If their ID changes in any way then code which looks them up based on that ID will break.

The question is, in ArcMap, can I reorder my TABLES in my layer list at all?

ArcMap 10.2
Oracle 10g

Comment: It seems that in a mxd the tables are ordered by their order of inclusion. You would need to remove the ones that are out of order and then re-add them in descending order... it's that or re-write the tool to obtain the table ID by table name.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to provide more details about how you are trying to read your layer/table list, please?  A code snippet to illustrate that and where you are stuck would be most helpful.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Thanks for your comment. I thought this might be the case and I will make changes to have all code work with layer names. For today I am just removing and reconfiguring some layers to get the correct order. Just a band aid :)

Comment: @PolyGeo There is no help required for code on this one. The question was about finding out if this was possible or not so I could stop wasting my time reading documentation.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are referring to as "my layer list".  Seeing the code used to read that would I suspect have made it more obvious what it was.  Are you talking about the order seen in the List By Source View of the Table of Contents, what gets returned by ArcPy's ListLayers/ListTables, or something else?  Personally, I treat what's in the TOC as volatile and would only access layers and table views in a map using their name, or data source (if 1:1) rather than order.

Comment: Instead of removing the tables and re-adding them how about repointing the tables to a new table? Go to the source tab of the table properties and hit 'set data source' button to change the reference to the new table... Order then wont change but will now reference the new location.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson both are good work around solutions and all is good now. Onto changing the code to work with names.

Comment: @PolyGeo There is no opinion in this one since it doesn't matter what layer list the question is talking about. None of them allow the reordering of TABLES.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to the AddLayer, MoveLayer, InsertLayer functions that apply to table views. But from version 10.3, reordering layers/table views so that you can access them in a service  won't be necessary anymore, since you are able to assign them an immutable ID.

Extract from this [What's new in 10.3](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/documentation/whats-new/whats_new_in_arcgis.pdf) document:

> In ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Server and earlier, the layer and table IDs of a
> map and feature services were not preserved after altering the source
> map document. This required you to update any client applications
> consuming the service to use the updated layer and table IDs.
>
> In ArcGIS 10.3 for Server, you can now preserve the IDs of layers and
> tables in map and feature services. When you create or alter a map
> document, an option is now available that automatically generates
> immutable IDs for each layer and table in the map document. If you
> select this option, the layer and table IDs are preserved after
> publishing or republishing; you are no longer required to alter client
> applications that consume the map service. If desired, you can replace
> the auto-generated IDs with your own custom IDs.

ArcGIS 10.3 will normally be released the week of December 9, and it's already available as prerelease for customers with a valid maintenance contract.

Comment: if you also answer the question in your response I would be happy to mark it as the answer. It is both informative and helpful and for the first paragraph I really want any other reader to see a direct answer "No you cannot do this in ArcMap versions 10.2.2 or earlier"